# How should I autoload WordPress plugin classes using composer for testing?

Tags: php, wordpress, phpunit, composer-php

I'm working in a WordPress plugin, following the WordPress Coding Standards.

This is the current structure for the plugin:

```
.
├── includes
├── languages
├── views
├── class-plugin-admin.php
├── class-plugin.php
└── plugin.php
```

That said, I would like to use the Composer autoloader to load both classes (for unit testing purposes).

Today I've been loading them like this:

```
"autoload-dev": {
    "files": [
        "class-plugin.php",
        "class-plugin-admin.php"
    ]
}
```

However, not sure if this one would be the best way to do it.

So here are the questions:

- Should I move my classes to a subdirectory in the plugin?
- Which one would be the best way to load them via composer?

Answer (score 2):

### Should I move my classes to a subdirectory in the plugin?

You don't need to, but you can. It definitely makes developing the plugin a lot easier, and I would suggest to do so.

As you indicated, you probably already have tests, so why not go ahead and adjust the structure to something like this:

```
.
├── includes
├── languages
├── src
│   ├── Plugin.php
│   └── PluginAdmin.php
├── test
│   ├── PluginAdminTest.php
│   ├── PluginTest.php
│   └── phpunit.xml
├── views
├── composer.json
└── plugin.php
```

**Note** I adjusted the class names, because ideally, you probably want to use some way of PSR-4 autoloading for your classes.

For reference, see:

- https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/05/how-to-use-autoloading-and-a-plugin-container-in-wordpress-plugins/

### Which one would be the best way to load them via composer?

This largely depends on whether you want to move your classes to a sub-directory or not. Let's assume you did, and let's assume you were using `Toally\Amazing` as a namespace prefix for your classes:

#### PSR-4

Use the PSR-4 autoloader:

```
{ 
    "autoload-dev": {
        "Totally\\Amazing\\": "src/"
    }
}
```

For reference, see:

- https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#psr-4

#### Classmap

List the directory which contains the classes:

```
{
    "autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
            "src/",
        ]
    }
}
```

For reference, see:

- https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#classmap

Decide for yourself which makes the most sense for you!

### Autoloading in production

As you can see, I use the `autoload-dev` section to indicate that `composer` autoloading is only relevant for development, not for production. You would still need to

- require classes in `plugin.php` *or*
- implement autoloading for your classes in `plugin.php`

Take a look at

- https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/05/how-to-use-autoloading-and-a-plugin-container-in-wordpress-plugins/

which provides a corresponding example for autoloading classes from your plugin.